# How to code alphanumeric serial number on Excel VBA (USABC001 to USABC002)

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started trying to code on Excel VBA for a project. I have very little knowledge of coding and I was hoping that someone could help me. I have a project, where I have to generate alphanumeric serial numbers based on the inputs on the UserForm. However, I am not able to do so.

Inputs on the UserForm include Country and Customer Name which will be needed to generate the serial number. (E.g. Country - US, Customer Name - ABC so my serial number should be USABC001). Subsequent entries with the same country and customer name should be generated as USABC002 and so on. If there is a new entry, the numbering should begin at 001. (E.g. Country - AUS, Customer Name - BCD, Serial number = AUSBCD001).

I hope that someone would be able to help and increase my VBA knowledge as well. Thank you.

This is the code I have tried but it does not work.

```
  Sub FindCustomerID()
Dim lastrow
Dim lastnum As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Customer Data")

If Me.cboCountry = "" Or Me.txtCustomerName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

c = 1

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
    If CustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
        'find last number that applies
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next currentrow

a = Left(Me.cboCountry, 3)
b = Left(Me.txtCustomerName, 10)

CustomerID = UCase(a & b & c)

Me.lblCustomerID = CustomerID

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a list that will build (no deletion), then you could use a `COUNTIF` with a wildcard and `Format` the answer. Btw, I'd suggest you use a seperator when concatenating string to prevent possible mishaps, e.g.: `US|ABC|001`

Comment: How do users make entries on the form?  You should consider using a dropdown so as to avoid typos.

Comment: @JvdV thank you for prompt replies and for helping a novice out ! I will keep that in mind and adjust my code to factor in your advice.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for pointing out a potential error that I did not foresee. I have changed the entries to a dropdown format as per your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment of CustomerID should precede your for loop or else, it won't have value to compare from. Hoisting the assignment of CustomerID before for-loop will make a difference.

```
'... your code from the top, down to lastrow = ...

'assign country and customer code
a = UCase(Left(Me.cboCountry, 3))
b = UCase(Left(Me.txtCustomerName, 10))

'there is no sense in using UCase to serial number
'save the process time of implicit casting from number to string.

'assemble them into CustomerID
CustomerID = a & b & c

For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
    If CustomerID = Cells(currentrow, 1) Then
        'find last number that applies
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next currentrow

're-assign the CustomerID with new serial number
CustomerID = a & b & c

Me.lblCustomerID = CustomerID
```

For sanity, you may adopt a self-documenting variable name like "countryCode" instead of "a", "customerCode" instead of "b" and "serialNo" instead of "c". So that when you come back to your code after a while, it will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: This has worked for me. I have also taken your advice and changed my variables to the ones you have suggested. I had to move the re-assignment of my customerID to below the 'End If' for it to work. Thank you for helping a novice out !